# Long For Loop Excecution Time

Tags: python, matlab, numerical-methods

I am attempting to compare the numerical output of a MATLAB script to that of numpy.

The task, from a homework assignment, is to **add the value of 10^-N to itself 10^N times**.

The goal is to demonstrate that computers have limitations that will compound in such a calculation.  The result should always be 1, but as N increases, the error will also increase.  For this problem, **N should be 0, 1, 2, ..., 8.**

My MATLAB script runs quickly with no issues:

```
solns = zeros(1, 9);

for N = 0:8
    for ii = 1:(10^N)
        solns(N+1) = solns(N+1) + 10^-N;
    end
end
```

However, using Python 3.8.12 on an Anaconda installation with numpy, this code will not terminate (See Update, code does execute):

```py
import numpy as np

solns = np.zeros((9, 1))

for N in range(len(solns)):
    for _ in range(10**N):
        solns[N] += (10**-N)
```

Is there an error in the Python code or is there some significance difference between the languages that creates this result.

**EDIT:**

I let the python code run for awhile and it eventually terminated after 230 seconds.  The whole array printed out as just [1., 1., 1., etc.].

For reference, using the `tic` `toc` commands on MATLAB, the program was executed in 0.155760 seconds

Comment: MATLAB these days is really fast even when you're looping due to JIT compilation and whatnot. Python loops are notoriously slow. But let me challenge your approach: are you sure you're not allowed to use a single array of length `10^N` and sum its values? It would be _a lot_ faster, although more memory intensive especially at the end (for `N = 8` you'd need about 800 MB of RAM for a double array).

Comment: @KellyBundy You are correct, about 3.8 minutes.  Just posted the edit

Comment: Values in your numpy array get printed differently than scalars. Print `solns[-1]` instead and see that it's not exactly 1. Or even better: look at `solns - 1` for differences from exact 1.

Comment: @AndrasDeak Had not heard of JIT compilation.  I like your suggested approach and will try it.  Also had never seen `solns[-1]`

Comment: The effect of this exercise is much more impressive if you use single-precision floats in the computation (`solns = zeros(1, 9, 'single'); ` in MATLAB). Because the rounding error is larger. Much larger!

Comment: @KellyBundy The edit I posted contains the new information.  For reference here, MATLAB executed the calculations in 0.155760 seconds while using tic-toc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're rather abusing NumPy there. Especially the `+=` with an array element seems to take almost all of the time.

This is how I'd do it, takes about 0.5 seconds:

```
from itertools import repeat

for N in range(9):
    print(sum(repeat(10**-N, 10**N)))
```

Output ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcoxDoAgDEDRnVN0pEQTjZMegjswgDYRSkodPD1q/Mtbfr314LL0noQzkEZR5rMB5cqiILHGoMYkFvBABSSUPdoVNwNvVaiobVe2/2jnybnRD/DpEbH3Bw)):

```
1
0.9999999999999999
1.0000000000000007
1.0000000000000007
0.9999999999999062
0.9999999999980838
1.000000000007918
0.99999999975017
1.0000000022898672
```

As @AndrasDeak commented, it's fast due to several optimizations. Let's try fewer optimizations as well.

First, only get rid of NumPy, use simple Python floats. Your original btw takes me about 230 seconds as well. This only about 29 seconds:

```
for N in range(9):
    total = 0
    for _ in range(10**N):
        total += (10**-N)
    print(total)
```

Next, don't recompute the added value over and over again. Takes about 11 seconds:

```
for N in range(9):
    total = 0
    add = 10**-N
    for _ in range(10**N):
        total += add
    print(total)
```

Next, get rid of `range` producing lots of int objects for no good reason. Let's use `itertools.repeat`, it's the fastest iterable I know. Takes about 9 seconds:

```
from itertools import repeat

for N in range(9):
    total = 0
    add = 10**-N
    for _ in repeat(None, 10**N):
        total += add
    print(total)
```

Or alternatively, about the same speed:

```
from itertools import repeat

for N in range(9):
    total = 0
    for add in repeat(10**-N, 10**N):
        total += add
    print(total)
```

Simply put it into a function to benefit from local variables being faster than globals. Takes about 3.3 seconds then:

```
from itertools import repeat

def run():
    for N in range(9):
        total = 0
        for add in repeat(10**-N, 10**N):
            total += add
        print(total)
run()
```

That might be the fastest I can do with an ordinary clean `for` loop (loop unrolling would help some more, but ugh...).

My `sum(repeat(...))` version lets C code do all the work (and `sum` even [optimizes](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b70690bb37cc4bac695051484734eede0c1f9ada/Python/bltinmodule.c#L2439-L2441) the [summation of floats](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b70690bb37cc4bac695051484734eede0c1f9ada/Python/bltinmodule.c#L2497)), making it still quite a bit faster.